# How long should I keep the phone ringing?

Tags: professionalism, project-management, phone

I sometime find myself in project manager's shoes and need to remind people of duties they have to carry out for assigned projects. I do not want to be too pushy but after a few emails I tend to call them. If they do not pick up quickly I wait a couple rings and then hang up, send a reminder email, and eventually go see them in person. You get the idea.

Let's focus on the phone part. The phones do not have voicemail. As a rule of thumb, I wait for 20 seconds for people to pick up in order not to disturb all the people in their vicinity with the tone. My assumption being, 20 seconds are sufficient for someone to pick up a fixed line, if they are available (the same *wait time* would probably also work for mobiles).

Is that a *reasonable* practice? How long should I keep the phone ringing?

Comment: 20 seconds is very reasonable. I would argue that it shouldn't get to the point where you have to call them anyway. If people don't check their messages, and/or don't reply, there might be a cultural problem with people ignoring communications.

Comment: If I just missed your call (say, I just returned to my desk and then you hung up), how easy is it for me to call you back?

Comment: @AndreiROM Your comment makes the most sense as the answer.  After a user made comments which I agreed with regarding my initial answer, I removed mine.

Comment: @Brandin Well, that depends. Something weird is that the IP phone system does not have a "built in" phone log. Which means, if you do not have the windows companion app, you do not see missed calls at all (as far as I've experienced). I'm in a _branch office_ in a large multinational, but it does not seem there is any voicemail. We are more prone to use "phone rings" where other team members would pick up if someone is not there. Otherwise, indeed, email follow-ups are commonplace.

Comment: Your company can afford phones for employees but not voicemail? Intriguing.

Comment: @corsiKa The phone setup did surprise me. Yet, I believe that even if there was a voicemail people would not use it that much. The missing _embedded_ phone log on the other hand, I find very lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

20 seconds is very reasonable. I would argue that it shouldn't get to the point where you have to call them anyway.

If people don't check their messages, and/or don't reply, there might be a cultural problem with people ignoring communications. Or maybe ignoring *your* communications.

I would start keeping track of who doesn't seem to reply to your emails, and whether there's a good excuse for it or not (were they in a meeting?). If you can identify a pattern of certain people not replying, you may wish to take it up with them, or your manager.

> **Note:** remember that you can mark emails as urgent.

Comment: That's a start. I would like not to have to call people in a lot of instances, but I found that it works much better than sending loads of email and then bringing it up to management's attention. Email _urgency marks_ are largely ignored or misused. @SnWhte I've also tried using reminders, it was not very welcomed so I don't really do it anymore. I do see a pattern of people _dodging_ my questions when they are a bit too _annoying_, I'm thinking about discussing this topic as well on another thread maybe, when I have more clues on how to put it.